# Issue tracking with SourceTree?

Tags: issue-tracking, atlassian-sourcetree

Does SourceTree(git client) include any support for issue tracking?  If not does anyone know of another issue/bug tracking utility that integrates with SourceTree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jira, built by Atlassian, is exactly what you are looking for (https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira).

Comment: Thanks.  I had also missed that it is possible to do issue tracking directly on Bitbucket's site.

Comment: You can do directly in Bitbucket but as suggested earlier Jira would be the best way to go. They are integrated and work nicely together

Answer (score 1):

You can change status of issues as well as link a commit with existing issues via your commit content.

For completed tips, read this official document : https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/resolve-issues-automatically-when-users-push-code-221451126.html